# How can I manage different versions of Python on Mac?

Tags: python, python-3.x, installation, path

It seems there're different versions of Python installed on my Mac, as shown below. And they're installed under the same folder, EXCEPT python 3.8.1, whose folder path is bit weird to me. Does it mean this version has been installed wrongly or something?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDdad.png)

Also, I found Python exists in different folder on Mac. How can I know which Python along with its dependencies and libraries I am using? and Is it necessary to delete other redundant ones because it seems really mess now. (I am new to Python, so these questions really bother me :()
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QOyVZ.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Python version manager like [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv). I would suggest this over the others like anaconda for a beginner.

Install it by

```bash
brew install pyenv
```

and make sure you follow the [guides](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv#set-up-your-shell-environment-for-pyenv) on setting it up for your shell, I assume you are probably using bash if you are a beginner, I skipped this step when I started and it was a pain setting it up later, so don't skip it

Then you can install a version of your choice by running `pyenv install <version goes here>`

To find all of the other Python installations, run `where python python3`, you may remove them if you like

To manage the dependencies, you can use [pyenv-virtualenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-virtualenv)

Comment: Thanks for your help! 
When I checked other Python installasions, I found the following: a) /usr/local/bin/python  b) /usr/local/bin/python c) /usr/local/bin/python3  d) /usr/local/bin/python3  e) /usr/bin/python3

I understand that Python in /usr/bin is fundamental, which cannot be deleted. But the other fours seem suggest I have installed Python2 and Python3 twice based on the directory. After I look into the file path, I ONLY find two of them (/usr/local/bin/python & /usr/local/bin/python3). So they are just shown twice in the terminal, which is a bit confused.

Answer (score 0):

This is your answer to manage Python versions

https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/installing-packages/